# How can I track the SQL commands sent to a local SQL Server from VS2012?

Tags: sql-server

I used to use the management studio but is this still what I should use now I am running code and developing with VS2012.

I saw there is now some SQL Server Data tools for VS2012. Can I use these to watch SQL and Query plans or should I download the Management tools ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to trace commands.

Answer (score 0):

The data tools just allow you to create database projects in VS2012, to look at the commands being run and view execution plans, you will need the management tools, SQL profiler to look at the commands and then SSMS to retrieve and view the execution plans.

For execution plans, you could of course use another tool like SQL Sentry, but you still need the management studio to get the profiler.

Comment: Is there a free version of management studio? It seems like I am using SQL Express. Can I still see statement plans for that? Thanks.

Comment: SP1 of SQL Server Express 2012 Advanced Services includes the full SQL Management Studio which will allow you to view execution plans, this has the profiler included as well.